# Starting an application in iPhone after I Receive a Call from a Particular Number

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5

First in my application i register With a Mobile number after that if i get a call from that mobile number after the end of that call i want open that Application (initially App is not Started) or I Want to show a Button on the Screen.
is This is possible in iOS?

if possible then give me some idea to start this application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. What you can check is `CTCallCenter.currentCalls`
However this will only give you information if there actually is a call. 
There is no official API to interact with the phone and dig deeper than that.

Also note that if a call is received, your application will be pushed to background and is no longer the active app.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [CoreTelephony Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603). The [`CTCall`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590) class provides information about the call state.

```
extern NSString const *CTCallStateDialing;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateIncoming;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateConnected;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateDisconnected;
```

[`CTCallCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604)

`keep in mind that if you kill your app from the app switcher (i.e. swiping up to kill the app) then the OS will never relaunch the app regardless of push notification or background fetch. In this case the user has to manually relaunch the app once and then from that point forward the background activities will be invoked`

Comment: Thaks for u r answer. i Want to Start the app and send message to the User who called me. is it possible?